# How to intercept clipboard operations on Linux Wayland/Mutter/GNOME

Tags: linux, clipboard, gnome, gnome-shell

I'm looking to send a popup notification whenever an entity is copied/pasted/dragged&dropped. I've spent countless hours looking at source code, researching, and testing code modifications to Mutter. I've also tried experimenting with gnome-shell extensions and creating a Wayland client to no avail. The system I'm trying to implement this on is a RHEL 9.3 machine running Wayland/Mutter 40.9/gnome-shell 40.0.

My biggest question is where the clipboard operations are actually programmed in the source code. What would be the best course of action for this? I've looked at virtually every open-source clipboard manager made by the community and they're either incompatible with my setup, or I have had no luck in modifying them to fit my purpose.

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if you'd like any more information regarding something specific.